# Establish multiple Database Connections Using JPA and Spring Framework

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

How do i connect to multiple database at run time using **JPA and Spring Framework.** The connection should be done when a user has **logged in**. I store my users in **Db.Master** and after a successful login, i should change the operation database connection for that logged in user at **run time.**

Answer (score 0):

Read this blog on Spring Dynamic Datasource Routing [using XML](https://spring.io/blog/2007/01/23/dynamic-datasource-routing/) OR
[Using Annotations](http://fedulov.website/2015/10/14/dynamic-datasource-routing-with-spring/).

You will get the idea.

Comment: Then can you please upvote the answer, if it really helps you in finding the solution. Or you can mark it as an answer if it is.